# z-index overlap different element parent versus different parent nth child

Tags: css

**Overview:**

There are 2 containers which called **top-parent** and **middle-parent** and **middle-parent**'s child should overlap the **top-parent**.

[image]

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="top-parent" class="wuuh">
    <div id="top-child">
        I SHALL BLOCK YOU
    </div>
</div>

<div id="middle-parent" class="wuuh">
    <div id="middle-child">
        <div id="middle-cousin">
            <div id="middle-niece">
                <div id="middle-priest">
                    NO!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#top-parent { z-index:102; }
    #top-parent #top-child {  background:#ea1248; width:400px; height: 200px; }

#middle-parent { z-index:101; background:#ccc; width:400px; height:200px; text-align:right; margin-top:10px; } 
    #middle-parent #middle-child { background:#333; height:100px; }
    #middle-child #middle-priest { z-index:200; width:95%; color:#fff; background:#4679bd; padding-right:5%; }
.wuuh { position:absolute; }
```

This what it looks like if we position **both** parents into **absolute**.

[image]

What I want to happen is for the **middle-priest** should overlap the parent 1 while overlapping the parent 2's child except for middle-priest.

**Desired Result:** (photoshopped)

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Here's a fiddle link [CLICK ME](http://jsfiddle.net/Vigiliance/M2a9H/)

Answer (score 0):

hey wesley i guess you are looking like this :- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/M2a9H/4/)

I have removed the height & Z-indexing see mentioned below the css how i achieved your desired result....

**CSS**

```
#top-parent {  }
#top-parent #top-child {  
background:#ea1248; 
width:400px; 
height: 200px; }

#middle-parent { 
z-index:101; 
background:#ccc; 
width:400px; 
text-align:right;  
} 
    #middle-parent #middle-child {
background:#333; 
}
    #middle-child #middle-priest { 
z-index:200; 
width:95%; 
color:#fff;
background:#4679bd; 
padding-right:5%; }
.wuuh { 
position:absolute; 
}
```